# Slow to set DataGridView DataSource to DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, backgroundworker

I have a DataTable, fully populated, which I want to set to a DatagridView:

```
gdv.DataSource = dt;
```

However, this is painfully slow. The filling of the DataTable is very quick, but just this one line above takes ages. Is there any way to speed this up or perform it in another thread?

There is no interaction after this point. Just the simple statement above!

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you use the same line of code, but with a dt of only 10 records--fast or slow?

Comment: How many records are in the data table and how large are the values (are there any large text fields?)

Comment: Very quick with very small table (10x10), in original table there are up to 400 rows, maybe 100 columns (max). Longest string field is around 10 chracters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the formatting options, especially the `Fill` -related properties. Those are AutoSizeColumnMode and the individual column styles.

Adjusting columnwidths for all rows involves a lot of calculation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Fill related? I cannot see this anywhere. Any in particular?

Comment: autosizecolumnmode, and individual column styles

Comment: Just the autosizecolumnmode has actually sped it up considerably! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a fix. The problem is that the framework re-resizes the columns once per row in the new datasource (why??). And of course it needs to loop over all rows each time, resulting in an O(n^2) operation. So sadly it looks like you must turn off autoresize before setting the datasource, then manually call the AutoResizeColumns method.

```
grdChanges.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None
grdChanges.DataSource = schemaChangesSpreadsheet.Changes
grdChanges.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells)
```

Turns out that Microsoft tells you to do this in an article "Best Practices for Scaling the Windows Forms DataGridView Control" which might help you if you have a different UI setting that has the same heavy computation issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx

Answer (score 1):

With this code I have good results:

```
dtgvPlanificado.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
dtgvPlanificado.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
dtgvPlanificado.DataSource = DS.Tables("LV1");  
dtgvPlanificado.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;  
dtgvPlanificado.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: This is very good: 3.577 ms => 98 ms, when you first set the ColumnHeadersVisible to false and then to true.

Answer (score 0):

AutoSizeColumnsMode is the real bottleneck ... and 11 seconds become 15 ms.

Here is what I was looking for:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Sub BeginLoadData(dataGridView As DataGridView)
    dataGridView.Tag = dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode
    dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None
End Sub

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Sub EndLoadData(dataGridView As DataGridView)
    dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = CType(dataGridView.Tag, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode)
End Sub
```

Comment: The question is in c#

Answer (score 0):

for me changing `RowHeadersWidthSizeMode` from:

```
DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
```

to:

```
DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders;
```

was extremely helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the autosize rows can also play a role.  This works well for me.  Took the databinding from ~1 sec to 0.1 sec.  I wish everything was that easy to get a 10x speed up!

```
dgvProperties.DataSource = Nothing
dgvProperties.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None
dgvProperties.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None
dgvProperties.DataSource = datatable
dgvProperties.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
dgvProperties.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
```